# Ubuntu won't shut down or restart

Tags: shutdown, reboot

When I shut down or restart my laptop with Ubuntu 15.04, the screen goes off but the LED lights are still on. In other words the laptop does not fully go off when a try to shut down or restart the system. What could be the issue?

Comment: Related: The [old post](http://askubuntu.com/q/254838/37165) and [even older post] were asking similar question but remain unresolved. Their answers suggested few possibilities, including problems in power management, graphic driver, linux kernel, etc. Then again, what have you tried so far; Have you at least installed latest updates?

Comment: i just updated the system yesterday and the problems is still there

Comment: The real problem is that some device in the system doesn't have the correct driver.  Updating to the latest version with the latest drivers may help, but that's assuming the device in question *has* a driver in the latest version.  Questions like this can only be properly answered with a list of all the devices in your system, especially video.

Answer (score -1):

I've been having the same issue, it's extremely annoying! However I found (after days of research) a solution that may not solve the "wakeup after suspend" problem, but now my system is shutting down and restarting as it should. Even though I can't find the original post, the site I found it from was stephenwagner.com. Here is what they suggested and it worked out fine for the "shutdown issue": Open Terminal and open the GRUB file

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

type your password and Enter (no characters appear here)

It is now in editing mode of your Grub configuration file. Be careful! Any wrong changes may destroy your system startup options!

Find the line that says:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it by adding nomodeset

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

After that press `Ctrl+o` ("write out") and then `Ctrl+x` ("exit")

Then, to save changes, update the Grub File in terminal using

```
sudo update-grub
```

Once done, reboot your machine. It should be working now. If not, please let me know!

Comment: This solution will prevent graphics drivers (e.g. Nvidia) from being used.

Comment: Oh OK, didn't know about that. My graphics run on AMD Radeon and worked fine after the change. Thank you for the warning! Cheers

Comment: In some situations, this is the correct answer.  In other situations, this will disable critical features in the video card, but it might be a good temporary solution until the correct video drivers are installed.  In yet other situations, the video driver isn't a problem (but something else is) and this will not help at all.